# Optimize fetching data from entity objects

Tags: 8, entities, database

Currently we are using EntityTypeManager to either load or loadMultiple :

```
$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
```

This creates and returns objects of nodes which I think uses much resource on the server (since it fetches all fields). **We're also trying to fetch around 500 nodes, and each has over 80 fields.**
We only want to fetch certain fields.

Does anyone know a way to query and fetch only the certain fields needed?

Comment: I'd rely on the Database API to make a custom query that will fetch only the certain fields you need. See Philipp Zedler's answer in the post mentioned by @leymannx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a custom query to be more efficient, here is an exemple :

```
$connection = \Drupal::service('database');
$select = $connection->select('node_field_data', 'n');
$select->fields('n', ['nid', 'type', 'title']);
$select->condition('n.status', 1, '=');
$select->condition('n.type', ['page', 'article'], 'IN');
$select->leftJoin('node__body', 'body', 'body.entity_id = n.nid');
$select->fields('body', ['body_value', 'body_summary']);
$result = $select->execute()->fetchAll(); 
//  print $result[0]->body_value;
```

You have to join table for each field you need to get. Note that `$result` does not contain hydrated `Node` objects but stdClass; this could work with all kind of database entities (i.e `User` or whatever).